# Displaying Tiles data with Time interval using Push Notifications in Metro Apps?

Tags: html, microsoft-metro, tiles, winjs

I have metro application in which I implemented Push notification concept for getting single message.If I get more than 1 notification,still my application tile is able to show only 1 notification(msg).Am not able to do how to display multiple notifications for time-specific.Means do I need to write any extra code for displaying multiple notifications on my tile.If so, where should I need do write either client-side or server-side?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to look at updating, and depending on what your end goal is, you may end up implementing the code either on the client, or the server, or a little of both.

For the scenario you describe, you need to use Windows Notification Services to push the notification each time you want a new tile notification. Typically, this is done by having a service running in the cloud (a website, or a Windows Azure service, or similar), that calls Windows Notification Service and sends a tile update to the app when something of interest occurs.

If what you want is for multiple notifications to cycle on the tile, that's enabled by calling the enableNotificationQueue method on the TileUpdater class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.tileupdater.enablenotificationqueue.aspx

Per the comment below, enableNotificationQueue works for any notification source. But if you want to pull information from a remote service, rather than using push, you can use scheduled polling as means of updating the tile using remote information, as described here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh761476.aspx

Combined with the call to enableNotificationQueue, it may also enable the scenario you're looking for.

Comment: Correction - once the notification queue is enabled, Windows will automatically cycle through up to 5 notifications for tile notifications **sent via any source** (push, periodic, local, scheduled).

Comment: @NathanKuchta Thanks for clarifying. I'd not had a chance to try enableNotificationQueue with push notifications, so it's good to know it'll work there as well.